# post-text-item can't accept commit

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

Can anybody suggest a good trigger that I can use in a text box. The operation that i intend to use in the text box is when the user changes the value in the text box, I call a Procedure that updates that value in the Database table with a commit. However ,so the moment the user changes the value and presses enter it should go to the next item, before which it updates the DB. It works fine in the KEY-NEXT-ITEM trigger. However, one problem is that say the user changes the value in the fld , but does not press tab or enter, but directly F10 to commit. My trigger in the text box(i.e KEY-NEXT-ITEM) does not fire. I tried a POST-TEXT-ITEM , but it does not let me use the ,COMMIT or NEXT_ITEM built ins. I want the trigger to fire the moment the user exits the item and also it should go to the next item in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger. This trigger is basically intended to validate value entered by user. It fires every time when forms decided, that user finished field value - when user leaves field, when user presses commit, etc.

Unfortunately you are not able to use COMMIT_FORM in this trigger. Forms recommend make direct database changes in transactional triggers only. To implement database change with commit, make your database procedure running in autonomous transaction:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_somethning (some_id NUMBER, some_value VARCHAR2) AS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  UPDATE some_table SET some_column = some_value
    WHERE table_id = some_id;
  COMMIT;
END do_somethning;
```

Yout WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger can be like this

```
BEGIN
   -- probably do some validations
   ...
   -- call your procedure
   do_something(:some_block.id, :some_block.your_field);
END;
```

Comment: That's a great idea ... thanks alot
NOTE: When I used "PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;" It gave me ORA-00060 deadlock detected
but when i removed it it worked well..
Thank you again

Comment: you are probably changing the same database record as selected in forms. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: are there more databse fields in block? How do you change that items?